# What class of Bachelor's (e.g. A3) required for Germany Blue Card?

Tags: germany, blue-card

What is the minimum Bachelor's class required for Germany Blue Card?  Is it A3, A4 or A5 or anything else?

Comment: What *are* bachelor classes A3, A4, A5? Googling does not turn up anything. Is this country specific? Please update your question

Comment: Google The Washington Accord and immigration.

Comment: @ouflak Yeah, but apparently Germany didn’t sign the Washington Accord.